# Transforming high-redundancy CSV data into nested JSON using jq (or awk)?

Tags: json, csv, awk, group-by, jq

Say I have the following CSV data in `input.txt`:

```
broker,client,contract_id,task_type,doc_names
alice@company.com,John Doe,33333,prove-employment,important-doc-pdf
alice@company.com,John Doe,33333,prove-employment,paperwork-pdf
alice@company.com,John Doe,33333,submit-application,blah-pdf
alice@company.com,John Doe,00000,prove-employment,test-pdf
alice@company.com,John Doe,00000,submit-application,test-pdf
alice@company.com,Jane Smith,11111,prove-employment,important-doc-pdf
alice@company.com,Jane Smith,11111,submit-application,paperwork-pdf
alice@company.com,Jane Smith,11111,submit-application,unimportant-pdf
bob@company.com,John Doe,66666,submit-application,pdf-I-pdf
bob@company.com,John Doe,77777,submit-application,pdf-J-pdf
```

And I'd like to transform it into the following JSON:

```json
[
{"broker": "alice@company.com",
    "clients": [
    {
        "client": "John Doe",
        "contracts": [
        {
            "contract_id": 33333,
            "documents": [
            {
                "task_type": "prove-employment",
                "doc_names": ["important-doc-pdf", "paperwork-pdf"]
            },
            {
                "task_type": "submit-application",
                "doc_names": ["blah-pdf"]
            }
            ]
        },
        {
            "contract_id": 00000,
            "documents": [
            {
                "task_type": "prove-employment",
                "doc_names": ["test-pdf"]
            },
            {
                "task_type": "submit-application",
                "doc_names": ["test-pdf"]
            }
            ]
        }
        ]
    },
    {
        "client": "Jane Smith",
        "contracts": [
        {
            "contract_id": 11111,
            "documents": [
            {
                "task_type": "prove-employment",
                "doc_names": ["important-doc-pdf"]
            },
            {
                "task_type": "submit-application",
                "doc_names": ["paperwork-pdf", "unimportant-pdf"]
            }
            ]
        }
        ]
    }
    ]
},

{"broker": "bob@company.com",
    "clients": [
    {
        "client": "John Doe",
        "contracts": [
        {
            "contract_id": 66666,
            "documents": [
            {
                "task_type": "submit-application",
                "doc_names": ["pdf-I-pdf"]
            }
            ]
        },
        {
            "contract_id": 77777,
            "documents": [
            {
                "task_type": "submit-application",
                "doc_names": ["pdf-J-pdf"]
            }
            ]
        }
        ]
    }
    ]
}
]
```

Based on a quick search, it seems like people recommend `jq` for this type of task. I read some of the manual and played around with it for a bit, and I'm understand that it's meant to be used by composing its filters together to produce the desired output.

So far, I've been able to transform each line of the CSV into a list of strings for example with `jq -Rs '. / "\n" | .[] | . / ","'`.

But I'm having trouble with something even a bit more complex, like assigning a key to each value on a line (not even the final JSON form I'm looking to get). This is what I tried: `jq -Rs '[inputs | . / "\n" | .[] | . / "," as $line | {"broker": $line[0], "client": $line[1], "contract_id": $line[2], "task_type": $line[3], "doc_name": $line[4]}]'`, and it gives back `[]`.

Maybe `jq` isn't the best tool for the job here? Perhaps I should be using `awk`? If all else fails, I'd probably just parse this using Python.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'd use perl, but python would work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a jq solution which uses a generic approach that makes no reference to specific header names except for the specification of certain plural forms.

The generic approach is encapsulated in the recursively defined filter `nested_group_by($headers; $plural)`.

The main assumptions are:

1. The CVS input can be parsed by splitting on commas;
2. jq is invoked with the -R command-line option.

```
# Emit a stream of arrays, each array being a group defined by a value of f,
# which can be any jq filter that produces exactly one value for each item in `stream`.
def GROUP_BY(f): 
   reduce .[] as $x ({};
     ($x|f) as $s
     | ($s|type) as $t
     | (if $t == "string" then $s else ($s|tojson) end) as $y
     | .[$t][$y] += [$x] )
   | [.[][]]
   ;

def obj($headers):
  . as $in | reduce range(0; $headers|length) as $i ({}; .[$headers[$i]] = $in[$i]);

def nested_group_by($array; $plural):
  def plural: $plural[.] // (. + "s");
  if $array == [] then .
  elif $array|length == 1 then GROUP_BY(.[$array[0]]) | map(map(.[])[])
  else ($array[1] | plural) as $groupkey
  | $array[0] as $a0
  | GROUP_BY(.[$a0])
  | map( { ($a0): .[0][$a0], ($groupkey): map(del( .[$a0] )) } )
  | map( .[$groupkey] |= nested_group_by($array[1:]; $plural) )
  end
  ;

split(",") as $headers
| {contract_id: "contracts",
   task_type: "documents",
   doc_names: "doc_names" } as $plural
| [inputs
   | split(",")
   | obj($headers)
  ]
| nested_group_by($headers; $plural)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a jq solution that assumes the CSV input is very simple (e.g., no field has embedded commas), followed by a brief explanation.

To handle arbitrary CSV, you could use a CSV-to-TSV conversion tool in conjunction with the jq program given below with trivial modifications.

### A Solution

The following jq program assumes jq is invoked with the -R option.
(The -n option should not be used as the header row is read without using `input`.)

```
# sort-free plug-in replacement for the built-in group_by/1
def GROUP_BY(f): 
   reduce .[] as $x ({};
     ($x|f) as $s
     | ($s|type) as $t
     | (if $t == "string" then $s else ($s|tojson) end) as $y
     | .[$t][$y] += [$x] )
   | [.[][]]
   ;

# input: an array
def obj($keys):
  . as $in | reduce range(0; $keys|length) as $i ({}; .[$keys[$i]] = $in[$i]);

# input: an array to be grouped by $keyname 
# output: an object 
def gather_by($keyname; $newkey):
  ($keyname + "s") as $plural
  | GROUP_BY(.[$keyname])
  | {($plural): map({($keyname): .[0][$keyname], 
                     ($newkey) : map(del(.[$keyname])) } ) }
  ;

split(",") as $headers
| [inputs
   | split(",")
   | obj($headers)
  ]
| gather_by("broker"; "clients")
| .brokers[].clients |= (gather_by("client"; "contracts") | .clients)
| .brokers[].clients[].contracts |= (gather_by("contract_id"; "documents") | .contract_ids)
| .brokers[].clients[].contracts[].documents |= (gather_by("task_type"; "doc_names")  | .task_types)
| .brokers[].clients[].contracts[].documents[].doc_names |= map(.doc_names)
| .brokers
```

### Explanation

The expected output as shown respects the ordering of the input lines, and so jq's built-in `group_by` may not be appropriate; hence `GROUP_BY` is defined above as a plug-in replacement for `group_by`.  It's a bit complicated because it is completely generic in the same way as `group_by`.

The `obj` filter converts an array into an object with keys $keys.

The `gather_by` filter groups together items in the input array as appropriate for the present problem.

#### `gather_by/2` example

To get a feel for what `gather_by` does, here's an example:

```
[ {a:1,b:1}, {a:2, b:2}, {a:1,b:0}] | gather_by("a"; "objects")
```

produces:

```
{
  "as": [
    {
      "a": 1,
      "objects": [
        {
          "b": 1
        },
        {
          "b": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "a": 2,
      "objects": [
        {
          "b": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

### Output

```
[
  {
    "broker": "alice@company.com",
    "clients": [
      {
        "client": "John Doe",
        "contracts": [
          {
            "contract_id": "33333",
            "documents": [
              {
                "task_type": "prove-employment",
                "doc_names": [
                  "important-doc-pdf",
                  "paperwork-pdf"
                ]
              },
              {
                "task_type": "submit-application",
                "doc_names": [
                  "blah-pdf"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "contract_id": "00000",
            "documents": [
              {
                "task_type": "prove-employment",
                "doc_names": [
                  "test-pdf"
                ]
              },
              {
                "task_type": "submit-application",
                "doc_names": [
                  "test-pdf"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "client": "Jane Smith",
        "contracts": [
          {
            "contract_id": "11111",
            "documents": [
              {
                "task_type": "prove-employment",
                "doc_names": [
                  "important-doc-pdf"
                ]
              },
              {
                "task_type": "submit-application",
                "doc_names": [
                  "paperwork-pdf",
                  "unimportant-pdf"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "broker": "bob@company.com",
    "clients": [
      {
        "client": "John Doe",
        "contracts": [
          {
            "contract_id": "66666",
            "documents": [
              {
                "task_type": "submit-application",
                "doc_names": [
                  "pdf-I-pdf"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "contract_id": "77777",
            "documents": [
              {
                "task_type": "submit-application",
                "doc_names": [
                  "pdf-J-pdf"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: thanks for providing this excellent solution, it does precisely what I need. Do you have any good recommendations on resources for getting more proficient at using jq? (its manual is thorough but not the easiest to learn from imo)

Comment: @JethroCao - The jq tag description includes a pointer to the jq FAQ, which in turn has a pointer to the jq Cookbook and other resources.  You might also like to look at my own attempt at an introduction: https://github.com/pkoppstein/jq/wiki/A-Stream-oriented-Introduction-to-jq

Comment: that's awesome, I'll definitely read through your tutorial!